# Limit tables shown in DevExpress Dashboard - Query Builder

Tags: devexpress, dashboard, devexpress-mvc

Im trying to limit the tables shown in the DevExpress Dashboard Query Builder.
I tried adding Queries like below but the Query Builder still show all tables in the database.

Is there a way to limit the tables shown in the Query Builder?

```
DataSourceInMemoryStorage dataSourceStorage = new DataSourceInMemoryStorage();
DashboardSqlDataSource sqlDataSource = new DashboardSqlDataSource("MyApp", customstringParams);


SelectQuery selectQuery = SelectQueryFluentBuilder
            .AddTable("EMPLOYEE_DETAIL", "Employee Master")
            .SelectAllColumns()
            .Build("Employee Information");

sqlDataSource.Queries.Add(selectQuery);

SelectQuery selectQuery2 = SelectQueryFluentBuilder
            .AddTable("EMPLOYEE_ATTENDANCE", "Shift Distribution")
            .SelectAllColumns()
            .Build("Shift Distribution");
        sqlDataSource.Queries.Add(selectQuery2);


sqlDataSource.Fill();
dataSourceStorage.RegisterDataSource("sqlDataSource", sqlDataSource.SaveToXml());

        DashboardConfigurator.Default.SetDataSourceStorage(dataSourceStorage);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish this task, use the approach described in [Query Builder - Limit the list of available Stored Procedures, Tables, or Views](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T622683/query-builder-limit-the-list-of-available-stored-procedures-tables-or-views).

Comment: But how can this be implemented to tables or views? Sample code is only showing the way to implement for Stored Procedures.

Comment: In this case, you will also need to override GetTables and GetViews methods (see [this](https://docs.devexpress.com/CoreLibraries/DevExpress.DataAccess.Sql.DBSchemaProviderEx._members) page for a complete list of the DBSchemaProviderEx class)